# How to use single field to store multiple data types (like string,object, array and etc) in mongodb using .net?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, webapi

As the title suggests We're on a journey to create a field on a collection that could be of any type in the MongoDb. It's simple to do with MongoDb but I'm unable to do it via C# Mongodb Driver.

We're creating ProductMetaData which contains Key-Value pair. Key will be a string and Value can be anything from string to object to array.

For example:

```
Value : "stringValue" 
Value: { Brand: "Coke", Measurement:"ml" } 
Value : Specs: \["14GB","Android","USB-C"\]
```

Here's the class

```
public class MetaData : Entity
    {        
        public string Key { get; set; }
        
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }
```

However saving directly with above Class Model saves the data as _t:JsonElement under the Value.

[image]

Further if I try to modify the model to **BsonDocument** like below the whole request in the HttpPost endpoint would come as null. Yes, I've looked up for it's resolution as well but was not able to find.

`public BsonDocument Value { get; set; }`

I've also tried other solutions like using BSON Serialization, using JObject, using dynamic but was not able to make any of them work.

In the end I want that any value provided in the "Value" field of the request should be persisted as is in the mongodb.